# Ingresar 3 notas de 10 alumnos, 1 materia y visualizar (problema python)

Tags: python

El problema me pide que Cree un programa de líneas de comando que permita ingresar 3 notas de 10 alumnos, 1 materia, y poder visualizar:

1. promedio de cada alumno
2. el alumno con mejor promedio
3. el alumno con menor promedio
4. cantidad y nombres de alumno con promedio mayor a 7 (aprobados)
5. cantidad y nombres de alumnos con promedios menor a 7 (desaprobados)

Estoy intentando hacer la primera parte pero no termino de lograrla:

```
#crear la lista alumnos
lista_alumnos = {} #diccionario vacío
lista_alumnos['nombre'] = [] #lista vacía de alumnos
notas = []
#crear la clase alumno y su método
class Alumno:

    def agregar_alumno(self, nombre, materia, nota1, nota2, nota3):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.materia = materia
        self.nota1 = nota1
        self.nota2 = nota2
        self.nota3 = nota3

for alumno in range(2):
    nombre=input("Ingrese el nombre del alumno:")
    lista_alumnos.append(nombre)
    materia=input("Ingrese la materia:")
    nota1=int(input("Ingrese la primer nota:"))
    nota2=int(input("Ingrese la segunda nota:"))
    nota3=int(input("Ingrese la tercera nota:"))
    notas.append([nota1,nota2,nota3])

for x in range(2):
    print(nombre[x],notas[x][0],notas[x][1], notas[x][2], materia)
```

Comment: Mmm... creo que sería mejor que la clave del diccionario sea el nombre del alumno y que su valor sea la lista de notas

Comment: Por que solo repites 2 veces el ciclo for? No debería ser 10 veces?

Comment: si, repito el ciclo for 2 veces para ir probando el programa más rápido

Comment: Lo solucionaste? Antes uba a publicar una respuesta pero no tuve tiempo, si aún no lo solucionas avisame

Comment: aún no lo he solucionado

Comment: lo siento por la demora, ya publique la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno vamos a solucionar tu problema, primero vamos a definir una mejor estructura especifico para este problema, como la siguiente.

```py
lista_alumnos = {
    'nombre':{ 
        'materias': {
            'materiax': ['notas']
        }
    }
```

Bueno para la primera función de agregar alumnos no hay mucho que hacer solo crear el diccionario y agregar el alumno, materia y las notas de acuerdo al modelo anterioir.

```py
Ecreamos la clase
class Alumno():
    def __init__(self):#establecemos su constructor
        self.lista_alumnos = {} #aqui se almacenaran los valores
    
    def agregar_alumno(self,nombre, materia, nota1,nota2,nota3): 
        self.lista_alumnos[nombre]={'materias': {materia: [nota1,nota2, nota3]}} #agregamos
```

Listo ahora como hacemos para sacar al alumno con mayor promedio?, primero debemos sacar el promedio de cada alumno y de acuerdo a ese promedio escoger al que tiene más. Lo podemos hacer de distintas formas

```py
   ...
    def mejor_promedio(self):
      for alumno in self.lista_alumnos: #iteramos en los alumnos
          for materia in self.lista_alumnos[alumno]['materias']: #iteramos en las materias
              notas = self.lista_alumnos[alumno]['materias'][materia]#obtenemos las notas
              #guardamos el resultado como tupla (materia, promedio)
              self.lista_alumnos[alumno]['promedio'] = (materia, sum(notas)) 
      #aun no se obtiene al alumno con mayor promedio
```

También se puede optar por una compresión de lista, pero de forma diferente.

```py
    ...
    def mejor_promedio(self):
        #iteramos en los alumnos
        for alumno in self.lista_alumnos:
            #compresion de lista para obtener el promedio mas facil y rapido
            promedio = [sum(self.lista_alumnos[alumno]['materias'][materia]) for materia in self.lista_alumnos[alumno]['materias']][0]
            self.lista_alumnos[alumno]['promedio'] = promedio
```

Bueno hasta ahi hemos obtenido el promedio pero falta, obtener al alumno con el mayor promedio, para eso nos podemos ayudar de la función `max()`, en este caso vamos a usar un "truco" para hacer todo mas fácil, vamos a crear un diccionario promedio el cual va a tener los promedios de los alumnos. trabajare con la segunda forma (compresión de lista) por simplicidad

```py
    ...
    def mejor_promedio(self):
        promedios = {} #aqui se almacenaran los promedios
        for alumno in self.lista_alumnos: #iteramos en los alumnos
            promedio = [sum(self.lista_alumnos[alumno]['materias'][materia]) for materia in self.lista_alumnos[alumno]['materias']][0] #obtenemos el promedio
            promedios[alumno] = promedio #guardamos el promedio
        #utilizamos una expresion lambda para obtener el promedio
        # nos devuelva la "key" del mayor valor encontrado, en este caso algun alumno
        alumno_max = max(promedios, key=lambda prom: promedios[prom])
        return alumno_max
```

**Probamos**

```py
alumnos = Alumno()
alumnos.agregar_alumno('christiann','ciencia',10,4,6)
alumnos.agregar_alumno('jose','ciencia',10,6,10)

alumnos.mejor_promedio()
#salida -> jose
```

Listo problema resuelto, como dijiste que no podías con la primera parte, como tenias problema en esa parte te ayude solo en eso, intenta desarrollar el resto, si no puedes haces otra pregunta, con mucho gusto te ayudaremos :).

Answer (score 0):

Aquí presento una solución usando solo la biblioteca lista_alumnos:

```
lista alumnos={}    
for alumno in range(2):
    nombre=input("Ingrese el nombre del alumno:")
    materia=input("Ingrese la materia:")
    nota1=int(input("Ingrese la primer nota:"))
    nota2=int(input("Ingrese la segunda nota:"))
    nota3=int(input("Ingrese la tercera nota:"))
    lista_alumnos[nombre]=[materia,[nota1,nota2, nota3]]
```

Luego para iterar:

```
for alumno, value in lista_alumnos.items():
    print(alumno+" "+" ".join(value))
```

Espero que te sirva, estoy desde tlf así que no pude probar el código. En cuanto a la clase de alumnos que función tiene? Es algo que implementaras luego?

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder! hasta ahora logré solucionar la 1ºparte de esta manera:

nombre_alumno = [] 
notas = []
materia = []

for x in range(2):
    nombre=input("Ingrese el nombre del alumno: ")
    nombre_alumno.append(nombre_alumno)
    materia=input("Ingrese la materia: ")
    nota1=int(input("Ingrese la primer nota: "))
    nota2=int(input("Ingrese la segunda nota: "))
    nota3=int(input("Ingrese la tercera nota: "))
    notas.append([nota1,nota2,nota3])
    promedio = (nota1+nota2+nota3) / 3

for x in range(2):
    print(f"el promedio de {nombre} es {promedio}")

Comment: Luego, la parte de for x in range(2): print(f"el promedio de {nombre} es {promedio}") tengo que lograr que me imprima el nombre de los diferentes alumnos cargados x el usuario con sus respectivos promedios, pero solo me imprime el ultimo.. la clase de alumno era con la idea de cargar todas las propiedades de cada alumno para luego crear funciones con las cuales pueda saber su promedio, si esta aprobado, etc..

Comment: @Lucys_asd, soy nuevo en este sitio pero creo que el motivo por el que no fue bien recibida tu pregunta se debe a que no fragmentaste el problema, ademas de no mostrar (asi de un error) tu resultado al ejecutar el código

Comment: En cuanto al código, estas haciendo uso de 2 variables (lista_alumnos y notas) que tienen una relación en comun, si llegase a ocurrir un error (como pasar un index incorrecto a alguno de estos) posiblemente pase desapercibido, así para futuras referencias si quieres guardar una información con un index identificable como un string (estudiantes en este caso) usa plenamente las bibliotecas

Comment: Sobre la iteración, solo te da el ultimo valor porque range() no empieza por 0 si no por 1, es decir que si tienes 3 elementos en una lista: comidas = ['queso','jamón','pan'] y iteras:
> for x in range(2): print(comidas[x]), te va a dar como resultado 'jamón' y 'pan', ignorando por completo 'queso'

Comment: Yo también soy nueva en la web y en programación también.. voy a seguir practicando!! muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: No hay problema!